# An email says that my AdSense application has been successfully reviewed but the site says the application is stlill being reviewed

Tags: google, google-adsense

I got an email from adsense after submitting my application

> Your application has been successfully reviewed. Now you need to
>   create your first ad unit and place the ad code on www.example.com to
>   fully activate your account. Note that before your account is fully
>   activated, only blank ads will appear on your pages. Once your account
>   is fully activated, you’ll receive a confirmation email and begin to
>   see live ads. Please don't click on your live ads, even to test them –
>   doing so isn't permitted by the AdSense programme policies. Sign in to
>   Google Adense to create your first ad unit and get fully approved.

Then I sign in to Google AdSense account but it is still saying

> we are reviewing your site. Reviewing your site will take up to 3
>   days. We'll email you when we've finished.

and I am not able to click on any option in left side.

[image]
So how can I create ads?

Can someone help what to do next

Comment: For what it is worth, probably by morning you will be able log on and continue to deploy your ads. If not then, then probably by lunch. A short lag time is understandable. Be patient. It will work out.

Comment: thanks @closetnoc I got that  email  12 hours ago . But still i can't able to create ads . thats why I just want to be sure that i am not missing anything . But i am sure now that  i can do nothing from my side except waiting . Thanks for your comment

Comment: I seem to remember going through the same thing way back in the dark ages when wheels were upgraded from triangles to squares. ;-) I know you want to get started. Who can blame you? I did too. It may take a while longer. Cheers!!

Comment: Anytime! We are here for you. I have been around long enough to remember fire being sold as a flavor enhancer for meat. That should count for something!

Comment: It will be great, if OP answer this question himself, after few days :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm experiencing this same problem, but I got my email a week ago.  For that entire week, my account has said, "Reviewing your site will take up to 3 days. We'll email you when we're done."  I've already got the email saying the review is successful.

Any additional advice...?  It doesn't seem that waiting a little longer is doing the trick.

Comment: In other words, it appears that Google may have a problem right now.    You may just have to wait until Google fixes their bugs.

Comment: hey their are many others who are facing the same issue , nobody knows how much time it will take , I think this is a bug in google system, even the google experts are not answering this question . this same question asked many times  on google adsense forums  but experts are not replying.. for example  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/jVFDLDqclzY;context-place=forum/adsense

Answer (score 2):

I have found a couple Adsense forum threads detailing this problem, starting at the same time. 1/27/17 
The dashboard directly contradicts the 'success' email.
Almost definitely an internal Google problem... question is how to bring it to the correct peoples' attention.
Product threads are just user-based.